# I need a regular expression that matches sentences that end with one of two particular words

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches sentences that end with one of three words.

For example assume the three words are: miles and yards.

My_String = One October 5, 2012 a race was run in Washington, D.C. There were 400 runners in the race.  The distance of the race was ten miles.

Given the string I would like to match = The distance of the race was ten miles.

I have tried the following: regex = `/.\s.*[miles.|yards.]/`

and `match = match.regex(My_String)`
`

But this is matching all the sentence before the sentence I'm interested as well as the sentence I'm interested in.

Update:

Kirill Polishchuk has come up with a solution that seems to get me pretty close (see below). Unfortunately, when I put this into the Rubular expression tester it simply highlights the target sentence but does not return it as a match.

I'm starting to think that Kirill's expression is actually working but it may not be supported in the Rubular engine I'm using to test it.

Final Update:

The following expression successfully matched the target sentence:

```
([^.]*(?:miles|yards)\.)
```

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[^.]*(?:miles|yards)\.
```

In this regex I assume that sentence ends with `.` symbol. It is really complicated to determine bounds of sentence using regex.

Comment: This is very close. When I test in in Rubular it highlights the whole sentence but only returns yards or miles as the actual match.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor, I've updated answer. Now regex contains not-matching group (`?:`). Try it. I have no idea does your regex engine support this feature.

Comment: Not quite there.  Now it highlights the sentence but does not return anything as the match.  What does the : do? I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the first problem is that you're using square brackets when you should be using parentheses. **[abc]** matches a single character that matches any of the characters inside the square brackets.  So you're matching any line that contains **m** or **i** or **l** (and so on).

Another problem is that **.** has to be escaped if you really want to match that character; if not escaped, it's a special regex character matching any single character.  So you should a) move it outside the parentheses (you're just wasting space typing it twice) and b) escape it with a ****.

The first half of your regex is puzzling; it matches any single character (**.**), followed by a single whitespace item (**\s**), followed by any number of unspecified characters (**.***). What are you trying to achieve?